# calling .focus() on <input type="text"> in WKWebView causes keyboard lag

Tags: javascript, ios, html, keyboard, wkwebview

I'm building an app in HTML5 and Javascript using WKWebView.

I have a very plain text **input** that I want to call focus() on manually via javascript. It does work, the keyboard pops up and there is a cursor in the input however the iOS keyboard is very laggy when typing/deleting the first character. It takes over a second for the character to appear and for the keyboard to become interactive again.

Does anyone have any idea on how what the problem might be?

---

Comment: There is [a bug related to `WKWebView` and `element.focus()`](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=142757) that might be interfering

Answer (score 0):

Try using click() instead of focus(). Both will give you the same response provided u dont have any events attached to onclick of the text box.

Comment: unfortunately using click() doesn't improve the situation!

Comment: Can u try giving a default value after focusing on the field?

Comment: If it helps anyone: I had a bug where the voice input would fill in the text again after the focus on the input was lost & manually reset with JS again by calling .focus() -> using .click() instead fixed this bug

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem in an AngularJS app with `WKWebview` and we solved it by using `ng-click` event instead of `ng-focus` (only on iOS).